# Trying to export multiple variables in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I started creating a web app with the firebase database.  The firebase config is in a separate file that gets imported into the application.

Now I want to add firebase storage, but I can't seem to export both db and st.  I get an error message saying that vuejs doesn't support named exports.  I would export app instead and get rid of the db and st references, however my application already has tons of references to db.  Is there a simple way to export db and st?

```
const app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = app.database();
const st = app.storage();  //this was recently added

export default db;  //How do I add 'st' to the export in vuejs?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want,

you can export an object with `db` and `st` as properties, or export different variables.

this syntax is called ES6, which use modules. you can read more about them [here (2ality blog)](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) and [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports).

You can try:

```
export { db, st };
```

or

```
export const db = app.database();
export const st = app.storage();
```

Then, import them wherever you want.

```
import { db, st } from 'path/to/file'
```

Comment: This is when I get the error:"db.vue?6ea4:15 named exports are not supported in *.vue files".  This script is in a db.vue file, I'm afraid I'll have to rewrite a bunch of code.

Comment: try store them in regular .js file.
.vue file should be used for components.